# Python Pandas Select Index where index is larger than x

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements

Say I have a DataFrame `df` with date as index and some values. How can I select the rows where the date is larger than some value `x`?

I know I can convert the index to a column and then do the select `df[df['date']>x]`, but is that slower than doing the operation on the index?

Comment: The most idiomatic is probably [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing). But you could do something like `df[df.index > x]`.

Comment: you can just do the same with the index so if your index is already a date time then you can just do `df[df > x]` would just work

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Example of selecting from a DataFrame with the use of index:

```
from numpy.random import randn
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import timedelta as td
import dateutil.parser

d = dateutil.parser.parse("2014-01-01")
df = DataFrame(randn(6,2), columns=list('AB'), index=[d + td(days=x) for x in range(1,7)])

In [1]: df
Out[1]:
                   A         B
2014-01-02 -1.172285  1.706200
2014-01-03  0.039511 -0.320798
2014-01-04 -0.192179 -0.539397
2014-01-05 -0.475917 -0.280055
2014-01-06  0.163376  1.124602
2014-01-07 -2.477812  0.656750

In [2]: df[df.index > dateutil.parser.parse("2014-01-04")]
Out[2]:
                   A         B
2014-01-05 -0.475917 -0.280055
2014-01-06  0.163376  1.124602
2014-01-07 -2.477812  0.656750
```

Comment: The answer above is more robust, but if you want to get a quick query (for example, when using jupyter notebook) the following is also valid:  df[de.index > "2014-01-04"]

Comment: Can df.index be generalized to functions of the index? eg select even-numbered day?

Comment: Question what if one was interesting in Column A smaller than a certain number?

Answer (score 11):

The existing answer is correct, however if we are selecting based on the index, [the second method from here](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/preprocessing_dates_and_times/select_date_and_time_ranges/) would be faster:

```
# Set index
df = df.set_index(df['date'])

# Select observations between two datetimes
df.loc[pd.Timestamp('2002-1-1 01:00:00'):pd.Timestamp('2002-1-1 04:00:00')]
```

Comment: S in `Timestamp` should be lowercase in `pd.Timestamp`

Comment: thnx! Made it lowercase

Comment: This is not a correct answer. This would also return rows which index is equal to `x` (i.e. `'2002-1-1 01:00:00'` would be included), whereas the question is to select rows which index is larger than `x`

Comment: @bennylp Good point. To get strictly larger we could use a +epsilon e.g. pd.Timestamp('2002-1-1 01:00:00.0001')

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query):

```
In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     {'alpha': list('ABCDE'), 'num': range(5)},
    ...:     index=pd.date_range('2022-06-30', '2022-07-04'),
    ...: )

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
           alpha  num
2022-06-30     A    0
2022-07-01     B    1
2022-07-02     C    2
2022-07-03     D    3
2022-07-04     E    4

In [16]: df.query('index >= "2022-07-02"')
Out[16]: 
           alpha  num
2022-07-02     C    2
2022-07-03     D    3
2022-07-04     E    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers of ntg and Datageek to address the issues with each respective answer. Using `dateutil` requires an additional import. The `loc` approach is technically incorrect, as it cannot define a "greater than" relation without manually incrementing the time stamp, which can be worrysome when dealing with times in the nanosecond range.

Therefore, combining both approaches is the best solution IMO:

```py
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     ...:     {'alpha': list('ABCDE'), 'num': range(5)},
   ...:     ...:     index=pd.date_range('2022-06-30', '2022-07-04'),
   ...:     ...: )

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
           alpha  num
2022-06-30     A    0
2022-07-01     B    1
2022-07-02     C    2
2022-07-03     D    3
2022-07-04     E    4

In [7]: df[df.index > pd.Timestamp('2022-06-30')]
Out[7]: 
           alpha  num
2022-07-01     B    1
2022-07-02     C    2
2022-07-03     D    3
2022-07-04     E    4
```